# Visualization counting ongoing events

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elasticsearch index gathering session-like events, that have both a start date and an end date. The mapping of the index contains the following fields :

```
"dates": {
  "properties": {
    "start_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" },
    "end_date": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
}
```

I would like to create a visualization counting the number of ongoing events at a given time (my x axis would be time, and y the count of ongoing event).

How can I achieve this ?

I can easily find the number of currently ongoing events (using `_exists_` keyword for `end_date` in my query), but for past events, it looks a bit more tricky...

I have also tried using Timelion with `cusum()`, to aggregate events as soon as they are created, but I have not managed to delete them when they end (i.e. my sum is strictly increasing).